# date_trunc('minute', timestamp) equivalent in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mysql-workbench, date-arithmetic

What is the `date_trunc('minute', timestamp)` equivalent in MYSQL? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I like to use `date_format()` for this:

```
date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')
```

Or you can use date arithmetics (this works only if our initial value has no fractional seconds):

```
timestamp - interval extract(second from timestamp) second
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is to convert to seconds, divide by sixty, truncate, and convert back:

```
select from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(timestamp) / 60)*60)
```

What is handy about this is that it can be used for other intervals, such as every 15 minutes (or whatever) by tweaking the logic.

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplest [solution](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-minute-function.php) I've found.
MySQL MINUTE() returns a MINUTE from a time or datetime value.
`MINUTE(time1)`